# VM Resolution can't go over 640x480, even after guest additions were installed

Tags: xubuntu, virtualbox, resolution

This is on VirtualBox, guest is Xubuntu 32bits 14.04, host is Windows 8.1 64bits

I should point my hardware does not allow x86 virtualization, hence why VirtualBox only allowed a 32bits VM to be installed.

*Side note : It's an AMD FX 6300, although in the specifications it says virtualization supported, my BIOS says otherwise.*

Comment: To see if the video-driver was correctly installed with the guest additions open a terminal in the guest to issue `lsmod | grep vbox`. It should say `vboxvideo`.  If not you may have to re-install them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your VM is shut down, change the available video memory to something higher.  (I use 128 MB - the max allowed)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with Bodhi Linux. Something in the installer for vboxedition fails. You can temporarily work around the problem but running

```
vboxuser
```

If that corrects the issue, then you need to set the system to run `vboxuser` on start up. You can do this by adding the command to the `/etc/rc.local` file.